# Does AMPScript code count towards character length in Mobile Studio SMS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sms, mobilestudio

I have an SMS message which contains AMPScript which pushes the messages length past 160 character length.

MC warns me that this will use more than one message (and will be billed as such). Is this actually the case? It seems a little weird given that AMPScript content will never be sent to the SMS provider and is only used on MC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SMS charges are based on what is sent by the mobile aggregator.
Your "Message" in Mobile Connect can have as much AMPScript as you want, it is the final/rendered message that the character count is based on. Salesforce displays that warning as it is unable to calculate how long your final message will be

Be careful when using personalisation in your SMS messages. Customers with very long names can cause your SMS message length to be longer than intended.

Comment: thanks, it makes sense, is it documented anywhere?

Comment: I don’t have any documentation references on hand; however I believe there is a warning message about this in Mobile Connect when you put AMPscript in your message. In summary, SFMC will only send the rendered message to the SMS aggregator. This is also why the character count indicator disappears when using AMPscript, to prevent confusion.